# Make 2 different WooCommerce checkout pages?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm wondering whether it's possible to make 2 different checkout pages for 2 different products?

If a buyer chooses the product #1, he/she will be redirected to the checkout page #1. If he/she chooses the product #2, he/she will be redirected to the checkout page #2.

These 2 checkout pages have some same fields and some different fields. Some same fields are optional on the checkout page #1 but are mandatory on the checkout page #2.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: What if a user buys both products?

Comment: Hi @Ewout, Thanks for your question. A user may buy only one product at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure a user can only buy one product at a time, you need to disable shopping after a user has bought a product: otherwise a user could press 'back', and add the other product to the cart.

That said, you could try changing the checkout fields conditionally by putting this in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    //assuming only one product in cart
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
    }

    switch ($_product->id) {
        case '666': //product id for product 1
            //do stuff with the checkout fields
            break;
        case '999': //product id for product 2
            //do stuff with the checkout fields
            break;
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) for more info about changing checkout fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Merging the 2 different checkout pages into one is an approach.

Comment: is the answer not what you are looking for?